# MongoDB multiple $lookup and $group output

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm quite a newbie with MongoDB and I'm trying to retrieve a kind-of leaderboard based on two related collections and a third one, referencing one of the two, based on its different property.

[Schema can be found here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KNQwahLeCXM)

Consider a schema like the following one:

```
tree: { _id, company_id: string, company_name }
link: { _id, company_id: string, url: string }
analytics: { _id, tree_id: string, link_id: string, views: number, clicks: number, date: string }
```

A `analytics` document can have `tree_id, views` or `link_id, clicks` at once.
What I'm trying to achieve right now is a kind-of a "leaderboard" of the total clicks + views, starting from `analytics` collection, joining it with both `tree` and `link`, and finally retrieving the sum of clicks and views.
I have already managed to retrieve the sum of them for a specific `company_id`, with the following code

```
db.analytics.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "trees",
        as: "trees",
        localField: "tree_id",
        foreignField: "_id"
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "links",
        as: "links",
        localField: "link_id",
        foreignField: "_id"
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        $or: [
            {"trees.company_id": "1"},
            {"links.company_id": "1"}
        ]
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        views_count: {
            $sum: "$views"
        },
        clicks_count: {
            $sum: "$clicks"
        }
    }
}])
```

But I can't find a way to get a list of results like

```
{ company_id: 1, company_name: "foo", clicks: 100, views: 200 },
{ company_id: 2, company_name: "bar", clicks: 200, views: 200 }
```

and so on.

What I've tried so far is grouping by different `_id`, which is not working as I would expect

```
db.analytics.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "trees",
        as: "trees",
        localField: "tree_id",
        foreignField: "_id"
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "links",
        as: "links",
        localField: "link_id",
        foreignField: "_id"
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$trees.company_id",
        views_count: {
            $sum: "$views"
        },
        clicks_count: {
            $sum: "$clicks"
        }
    }
}])
```

Which does not assign `clicks_count` to a specific entry, but outputs something like

```
{ "_id" : [ "1" ], "views_count" : 6, "clicks_count" : 0 }
{ "_id" : [ ], "views_count" : 0, "clicks_count" : 48 }
{ "_id" : [ "2" ], "views_count" : 10, "clicks_count" : 0 }
```

I'm not even sure that this schema could be the best solution, so I will also appreciate any design suggestions or similar stuff.

Based on the comment below, I tried to deconstruct `trees` before grouping results, but it ended outputting the `company_id, views_count` only, without counting `clicks`, as following

```
{ "_id" : "2", "views_count" : 10, "clicks_count" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "1", "views_count" : 6, "clicks_count" : 0 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$addFields` to add company field, check condition if `trees.company_id` not empty [] then return `trees` otherwise return `links`
- `$arrayElemAt` to get first element from array
- `$group` by `company_id` and sum your counts

```
db.analytics.aggregate([
  { $lookup: { //... } },
  { $lookup: { //... } },
  {
    $addFields: {
      company: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          { $cond: [{ $ne: ["$trees.company_id", []] }, "$trees", "$links"] },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$company.company_id",
      company_name: { $first: "$company.company_name" },
      views_count: { $sum: "$views" },
      clicks_count: { $sum: "$clicks" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ID893F-e1rz)

Comment: So basically you are adding `company_id` from `trees` or `links` to the root document, allowing you to group all the documents by `company.company_id`? I didn't know how dirty mongodb can be. But, you saved my day! :)

Comment: actually mongodb is straight no need of multiple collections, your schema is look like mysql, and mongodb is nosql.

Comment: so you do suggest to use a single collection with analytics at root level (for `tree`), and having `links` nested with their own `analytics`? makes sense, but I'm unsure how it will affect performances

Comment: sure i don't know about your project concept but in quick i have just added a new collection at last and new query see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Sbj-2yT0q3b), so i have just added that common fields company_id and company_name and url in every analytics document. so we have removed 2 extra collections, basically in nosql it does not matter duplicate data/values in every document but prevent multiple collection and relationship collections. you can improve this schema more as per your project concept.